# How to Display a DIV with 'fixed' and 'inline-block' Added to its CSS Properties

Tags: html, css

I want to be able to display a **DIV** in a `fixed` position and have its `width` fit to content but each time I add `position: fixed;`, the div gets computed to `display: block;` and the div becomes full length.

**HTML**:

```
<div class='veil'></div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.veil{
    display: inline-block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 34%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: lavender;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> each time I add position: fixed;, the div gets computed to display: block; and the div becomes full length.

It's not `display: block`, it's `position: fixed` makes div stretch relatively to browser window, and since you have `left: 0` and `right: 0` you observe this behavior that div takes all window width.

Depending on your HTML structure you can use `position: absolute` instead or as pointed in comments (thanks @Paulie_D) don't use `right: 0`.

Comment: @Paulie_D If you remove the `right`proprety, the `div` will still be `diplay:block`.

Comment: No...it doesn't. It displays as inline-block....at least it does in the fiddle. It won't center...if that's what you mean.

Comment: Check under the computed styles for the `.veil`.

Comment: @Paulie_D - What do you mean by displays as inline-block? That it shrink-wraps, or something else?

Comment: Yes, sorry I deleted the comment but yes it "computes" as block but **displays** (thus shrink wrapping) as `inline-block"...and that I think was the point.

Comment: And actually if you look at this - http://jsfiddle.net/vynn9k0e/3/ under computed styles you can see that (by clicking the little-arrow to expand) it does show `inline-block` for the `.veil` div. The `p` inside it is `block` though.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `display:table` to shrink wrap, which `position:fixed` preserves. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/2c5y6u3h/

Answer (score 2):

Just add another container.
and split the contradiction in CSS between them.

**HTML**:

```
<div class='container'><div class='veil'></div></div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.container
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 34%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.veil
{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: lavender;
}
```